# Flutter-Not able to load Widget from StreamBuilder

Tags: dart, flutter

I am calling API using BLoC. On successful response, I need to call Widget named

> _moveToHomeScreen()

. 
Following is my code for that

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      //body: UserDetail(),
      body: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child:StreamBuilder(
          stream: bloc.validateUser,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              _moveToHomeScreen();
            }
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _createInputFields(),
                _createRegisterButton(),
              ],
            );
          }
        ),
    );
  }
```

AND

```
Widget _moveToHomeScreen ()  {
    print('inside move to home screen');
    return Center(
      child: Opacity(
        opacity: 0.5,
        child: Text(
          "Save a person to see them here!",
          key: Key("Placeholder"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Control goes into the Widget but I am not able to see desired output from Widget.

Comment: your `StreamBuilder` always returns `return Column(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Streambuilder never returns _moveToHomeScreen();**

```
override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
    // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    title: Text(widget.title),
   ),
  //body: UserDetail(),
  body: new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child:StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.validateUser,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return _moveToHomeScreen();
        }
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _createInputFields(),
            _createRegisterButton(),
          ],
        );
      }
    ),
 );
}
```

Just added **return** before `_moveToHomeScreen();`